# Sql server update zero value existing date

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have date value `2017-09-18 11:27:59.547` my table.

How can l update to `2017-09-18 00:00:00.000` on all records?

Can you give me sql script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should do the trick

```
UPDATE table SET field = CAST(field as DATE);
```

Comment: if you want all future values also to be without a time you could change the field type to `DATE`.